# Deploy Appveyor build as GitHub release without making a tag

Tags: github, appveyor

I have a project hosted on GitHub and I have it compiling with Appveyor.

I would like to set up Appveyor so that each build is deployed as a GitHub release, but with each build overwriting the last.  This way there will only be one GitHub release from Appveyor that will always have the latest build attached.

I can't see how to do this, because if I specify a `release` in `appveyor.yml` I get an error saying the release already exists (yes I want to overwrite it), and if I don't, then each deployment creates a new tag with the current build, which will litter the repository with useless tags.

On top of that, every time the release gets deployed, it creates a new tag which in turn triggers another Appveyor build.  This means every push to the repository triggers two identical builds.

Has anyone worked out a way to deploy to the same GitHub release continuously, replacing the files with the latest versions, and to prevent a new Appveyor build from being triggered in response to an Appveyor deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `force_update: true` to GitHub deployment provider settings to overwrite existing release.